# Pandas Merge not working correctly, there are lots of NaNs

Tags: pandas, merge

I have 2 datasets (See sample DFs below)

**SKU**

| SKU | Description |
| --- | --- |
| CDH21A | Screw |
| EG1 | Bolt |
| 00TTA | Drill |
| BBHRS | Screw |
| 434TFR34F | Screwdriver |
| 3QFF5Q4Y | Nail |
| AAA54Q3F | Timber |

**Sales**

| SKU |
| --- |
| 02cdh21a |
| 00eg11 |
| 0100tta |
| bbhrs22 |
| ggffg |
| fgjhty |
| rtrtrtrt |

What I'd like to do is merge the description column from the SKU DF to the Sales DF. The issue is that the SKUs in the SKU DF **can be** substrings in the Sales DF.

The code I currently have is outlined below, I strip any special characters and Whitespace from both DFs first.
I then create a list called key which finds the common SKUs in both DFs and then I try to merge.
Unfortunately when I merge I'm left with the following (The Description column is all NaN):

| SKU | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 02cdh21a | NaN |
| 00eg11 | NaN |
| 0100tta | NaN |
| bbhrs22 | NaN |
| ggffg | NaN |
| fgjhty | NaN |
| rtrtrtrt | NaN |

**Code**

```
SKU2= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Desktop\DF1.xlsx') 
Sales2= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Desktop\DF2.xlsx')



 # Change D.Types
Sales2['SKU'] = Sales2['SKU'].astype(str)
SKU2['SKU'] = SKU2['SKU'].astype(str)

# Strip whitespace
SKU2['SKU'] = SKU2['SKU'].str.strip()
Sales2['SKU'] = Sales2['SKU'].str.strip()

# Remove Special characters
SKU2['SKU'] = SKU2['SKU'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
Sales2['SKU'] = Sales2['SKU'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')

import re
Sales2['SKU'] = Sales2['SKU'].str.replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]","")
SKU2['SKU'] = SKU2['SKU'].str.replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]","")


Sales2['SKU'] = Sales2['SKU'].str.lower()
SKU2['SKU'] = SKU2['SKU'].str.lower()

# Create a list
key = Sales2['SKU'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(sorted(SKU2['SKU'].values, key=len,reverse=True))})", expand=False)

# Merge SKU column and TF column to the sales DF
Sales2 = pd.merge(Sales2, SKU2[['FRUIT']], left_on=['SKU'],right_on=key, how='left').drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: You need to make the values **identical** for a merge. So you question reduces to: what is the logic to make the labels identical?

Answer (score 1):

Change to lower case first:

```
sku_df['SKU_to_merge'] = sku_df['SKU'].str.lower()
```

Extract mergable strings:

```
pat = r'(%s)'%'|'.join(sku_df['SKU'].str.lower().unique())
sales_df['SKU_to_merge'] = sales_df['SKU'].str.lower().str.extract(pat)
```

And merge:

```
sales_df.merge(sku_df[['SKU_to_merge', 'Description']], on='SKU_to_merge', how='left')


        SKU SKU_to_merge Description
0  02cdh21a       cdh21a       Screw
1    00eg11          eg1        Bolt
2   0100tta        00tta       Drill
3   bbhrs22        bbhrs       Screw
4     ggffg          NaN         NaN
5    fgjhty          NaN         NaN
6  rtrtrtrt          NaN         NaN
```